# JQgrid search options not showing

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Following is my code , I am new to JQgrid and I did follow the example provided on the wiki, but for some odd Reason I'm unable to see any Search options on the navigation bar,  Any help would be really appreciated

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({

            url: "genxml3.php",
            datatype: "xml",
            mtype: "GET",

            colNames: ["A", "T", "E"],
            colModel: [

                { name: "A", Index: 'Name', width: 155 },
                { name: "T", width: 290 },
                { name: "E", width: 80, align: "right" ,sortable: false},

            ],
            pager: "#pager",
            height:"100%",
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [40, 80, 120],
            rownumbers: true, 
            rownumWidth: 40,
            sortname: "invid",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "Digital List"


        })

        });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', {edit:false,add:false,del:false}, {},   {}, {}, {multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true, showQuery: true}
         );

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to me the wrong place of `navGrid` call. Curruntly you placed it **outside of** `$(function () {...})` block. So the call of `navGrid` will be made *before* the grid is created and the `navGrid` failed. You need to move the line `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', ...);` one line above to fix the problem.

Additionally you should remove `Index: 'Name'` from the column `"A"`. First of JavaScript is case sensitive and there are only `index` and no `Index` properties. Moreover it's not recommended to use `index` property at all it it not really required. The option `sortname: "invid"` have probably not much sense because you don't have column having the name `invid`.

Another remark. You should include `gridview: true` option to improve performance of the grid and consider to use `loadonce: true` option. If you don't use `loadonce: true` option then the server (`url: "genxml3.php"`) have to implement server side paging, sorting and filtering (searching). In case of not so large dataset (for example less of 1000 or 10000 rows) it could be more effective if the server returns *all data* (initially sorted by `sortname` if you any use). jqGrid will save returned data in internal `data` parameter which are typical for usage `datatype: "local"` and then it will change `datatype` to `"local"`. So jqGrid will implement sorting, paging and filtering/searching **locally** without any request to the server. Typically local sorting works quickly as requests to the server if the number of rows is not so large.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback,  I did move the navGrid() one line above but I am still not able to see any search options.

Comment: May be I am missing a library or plugin that I have to include?

Comment: @hitek: Nothing more is required. Do you have the demo online?

Comment: I have the Xamp server installed on my local machine

Comment: it's a bit frustrating as I have not been able to display any search options even though I followed the example

Comment: @hitek: Just look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid.htm) or on the code from [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file) and compare it with youth.